# recyclerview in kotlin returns only 1 item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I don't know why it presents only one item.

```java
class MyRecyclerviewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerviewAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    val mData = arrayListOf<CardviewItem>(CardviewItem("TEST", "TEST1"), CardviewItem("TEST", "TEST2"), CardviewItem("AAA", "ABBB"))

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageview_cardview = itemView.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(R.id.imageview_cardview)
        val textview_cardview = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cardview)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cardview_items, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mData.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.imageview_cardview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
            holder.textview_cardview.setText(mData[position].text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is **CardviewItem** here? If **CardviewItem** is a model class containing two String type field, you can initilaize it like this:

```
val list = ArrayList<CardviewItem>()
```

Then you can get the value like this:

```
list[position].field1
list[position].field2
```